Memory issue with pictureBox.ImageLocation C#
I'm Making overlay program displays pictures on semi-transparent form depending on what key was pressed. The way i decided to do this: make second form(first form contains setting, menu, etc.), use GlobalKeyboardHook(because i need it to work while form is not focused), assign specified image in picturebox.imageslocation every time arrow key is pressed(idk if it's the best way to do this).
• Problem: after ~10 keys program freezes(debug shows that program using around 50 Mb), garbage collector starts working and then nothing happens. My pngs are 100-150 Kb.
void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode.ToString())
    {
        case "Back":
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = null;

            break;
        case "Up":
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\up.png";

            break;
        case "Right":
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\right.png";
            
            break;
        case "Left":
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\left.png";

            break;
    }
}

I tried to do something with Dispose(), but it closes the form too - i need form to be always visible.
Also tried pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); - this somehow doesn't clear image and it's still visible + there is an exception "Parameter is not valid." if i try to press arrow key after disposing.
GlobalKeyboardHook works fine without filling pictureboxes so the problem is in the image assigning.
I don't understand why replaced images still take place.

Can you try setting e.Handled to true before each break statement so no other notifications for each event go out?

nothing changed

What about just loading the images once, and then setting the Image property instead?

This works a bit better! at least adding image from properties doesn't freeze program on 50 mb, but anyway this approach accumulates stuff in memory(but this one is at least usable )

c# picturebox memory releasing problem But another option is to have 3 pictureboxes, all at the same location. One has up.png, one has left.png, and one has right.png. Show/hide the picture boxes as needed.
